# anchor with href to another html file but on pageload scroll to specific element by id

Tags: javascript, html, fullpage.js

I have 2 html files

html file 1 with name "index" which has header navigation menu with a inside li

```
<li><a href="sl/houses.html#slide-one-1">Stark</a></li>
<li><a href="sl/houses.html#slide-two-2">Lannister</a></li>
```

And the second html file with name houses.
inside tis html file i use fullpage.js plugin and i have 5 horizontal slides
so what i want is if i click on Stark button i go to the first slide
and if i click on Lannister i go to the second slide and i tried something like this but it does not work

this is the courasel of houses.html

```
<div class="carousel-inner" id="slide-one-1">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/ned.jpg');">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2 slide-paneli">
                            <div class="col-md-12  slide-paneli">
                             <a href="../index.html"> <img class="back-img" src="img/back.png" alt="back button"></a>
                            </div>                            
                            <h1>Winter is coming</h1>
                            <p>House Stark of Winterfell is one of the Great Houses of Westeros and the principal noble house of the North; many lesser houses are sworn to them. In days of old they ruled as Kings of Winter, but since the Wars of Conquest by House Targaryen they have been Wardens of the North. Their seat, Winterfell, is an ancient castle renowned for its strength.

Their sigil is a grey direwolf racing across a field of white, and their words are "Winter is Coming", one of only a few house mottoes to be a warning rather than a boast.[1] Members of the family tend to be lean of build and long of face, with dark brown hair and grey eyes. Several of the POV characters of A Song of Ice and Fire are members of House Stark.</p>


                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Starks</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="slide-two-2">
                <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/cersei.jpg');">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 slide-paneli">

                            <div class="col-md-12  slide-paneli">
                                 <a href="../index.html"> <img class="back-img" src="img/back.png" alt="back button"></a>

                            </div>
                            <h1>A LANNISTER ALWAYS PAYS HIS DEBTS!</h1>
                            <p>House Lannister of Casterly Rock is one of the Great Houses of Seven Kingdoms, and the principal house of the westerlands. Their seat is Casterly Rock, though another branch exists that is based in nearby Lannisport. Their sigil is a golden lion on a field of crimson. Their official motto is "Hear Me Roar!" However, their unofficial motto, equally well known, is "A Lannister always pays his debts."[2][3] The Warden of the West is a Lannister by tradition.</p>
                            <div class="row">

                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Lannister</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Any suggestions of how to make this work

Comment: Why 2 separate html files? In the fullpage.js examples, I see only one html file containing the menu and the content. This, for simplification. Still, I have made it work with 2 separate files, as you intend. Are you loading correctly the fullpage.js script (and, before that, jQuery ?)

Comment: Can you post the full content of your 2nd html file?

Comment: i think you misunderstood me the point is that the two buttons "Stark" "Lanniser" in index.html when clicked they navigate to the same location in houses.html because the second slide shows when the user click an arrow my question is is it possible slide once if you hit the Lanniser buttno when the houses.html opens

Comment: Hi Georgi, I'd give this a read through on the fullPage.js docs: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-links-to-sections-or-slides